# Probability of a consecutive sequence of 3 balls

Tags: probability

You have 6 balls, 3 white, 3 black. What is the probability of a sequence of 3 white balls (the white balls appear next to each other in the sequence) ?

My solution is:

There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to arrange the 6 balls on a line, while there are 4 ways you can put the 3 white balls next to each other. This results into:
$$\frac{4}{\binom{6}{3}}$$

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me.

You have $6$ balls, which you can order in $6!$ ways. Then, since balls of the same color are indistinguishable amongst themselves, you have to adjust, for a total of $$\frac{6!}{3! 3!} = \binom{6}{3} = 20$$
ways of arranging the balls in a sequence.

Then we can consider the three white balls as one object (so they always appear next to each other). We thus would have $4$ objects, and the number of ways to arrange them is
$$\frac{4!}{3! 1!} = \binom{4}{3} = 4$$
by the same logic as before (since you have to account that the $3$ black balls are indistinguishable amongst themselves).

So the probability of a sequence of 3 white balls is indeed
$$\frac{4}{20} = 0.2$$